# Passing Meteor.user() to a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm currently using [themeteorchef/base](https://github.com/themeteorchef/base) boilerplate project. It's been really helpful as I move from the Meteor/Blaze to Meteor/React world.

It's straight forward to pass subscription data to components via containers. But, trying to create a basic profile page has been surprisingly hard and I feel like I'm missing something simple. So far I've managed to pass the user object as a json string (which is not ideal).

My question is- what is the best way to pass a logged in user's info to a react component?

In my container, I have...

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import ViewProfile from '../pages/ViewProfile.js';
import Loading from '../components/Loading.js';

const composer = ({ params }, onData) => {
  const currentUser = JSON.stringify( Meteor.user() );
  onData(null, { currentUser });
};

export default composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(ViewProfile);
```

And my component is a simple display...

```
import React from 'react';
import NotFound from './NotFound';

const ViewProfile = ( { currentUser } ) => { 
  return currentUser ? (
    <p>{ currentUser }</p>
  ) : <NotFound />;
};

ViewProfile.propTypes = {
  currentUser: React.PropTypes.string
};

export default ViewProfile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working!

Passing Meteor.user (reactive data) via the container was still the right approach and it was getting to the component, however, in my component I simply needed to reference the specific object value (string or array).

So in my container:

```
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import ViewProfile from '../pages/ViewProfile.js';
import Loading from '../components/Loading.js';

const composer = (params, onData) => {
  const user = Meteor.user();

  if (user) {
      const currentUser = {
          fname: user.profile.name.first,
          lname: user.profile.name.last,
          email: user.emails[0].address
      }

      onData(null, { currentUser });
  }

export default composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(ViewProfile);
```

Then in my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import NotFound from './NotFound';

const ViewProfile = ( {currentUser} ) => {
  //console.log(currentUser);

  return (currentUser) ? (
    <p>{ currentUser.fname }</p>
    <p>{ currentUser.lname }</p>
    <p>{ currentUser.email }</p>
  ) : <NotFound />;  
};

ViewProfile.propTypes = {
  currentUser: React.PropTypes.object,
};

export default ViewProfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can access "Meteor.user()" anywhere, so you don't need to pass it from either Composer or Parent-Component.
Therefore, in your simple component, you may use:

```
import React from 'react';
import NotFound from './NotFound';

const ViewProfile = () => { 
  return (Meteor.user()) ? (
    <p>{JSON.stringify(Meteor.user())}</p>
  ) : <NotFound />;
};

export default ViewProfile;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Currently with this edit, Meteor.user is still returning as `undefined`. As I understand, Meteor.user() is reactive so on initial load it'll be undefined. Do I need to somehow check the .ready() for the users collection?

Comment: It seems that there are 2 cases which return undefined for Meteor.user()

Comment: (Sorry I mistyped) It seems that there are 2 cases which return undefined for Meteor.user(): 1 is user did not login, and 2 is right after the moment that user has just logged in, your page is loaded before Meteor.user() can be accessed! Actually, using composer as in your previous version is common and also a good way to deal with this user. Your own updated code is good now.

Comment: Meteor docs recommend calling meteor.user() minimally hence why it is sometimes better to pass it down as a prop to a component